# How to merge sets in better then O(len(set))?

Tags: python, merge, disjoint-sets, union-find, disjoint-union

I have a list of sets called `groups`. `groups[i]` is a set of labels (integers) that are part of the same group as `i`. For example,

```
# idx:     0    1    2        3    4      5        6        7
groups = [{0}, {1}, {2,5,6}, {3}, {4,7}, {2,5,6}, {2,5,6}, {4,7}]
```

indicates that

- `0` belongs to the group containing just `0`
- `1` belongs to the group containing just `1`
- `2`, `5`, and `6` each belong to the same group, namely the group containing `2`, `5` and `6`
- `3` belongs to the group containing just `1`
- `4` and `7` each belong to the same group, namely the group containing `4` and `7`

Sometimes it turns out that two groups are the same. For example, say we found out that `4` and `5` belong to the same group. Then we have to merge group `{2,5,6}` with group `{4,7}`. After this merge, `groups` should look like:

```
# idx:     0    1    2            3    4            5            6            7
groups = [{0}, {1}, {2,4,5,6,7}, {3}, {2,4,5,6,7}, {2,4,5,6,7}, {2,4,5,6,7}, {2,4,5,6,7}]
```

Naively, this would require updating `groups[2]`, `groups[4]`, `groups[5]`, `groups[6]` and `groups[7]` or, in general, when merging `groupA` with `groupB`, it would require `len(groupA) + len(groupB)` updates.

---

A more efficient approach, would be if instead of having multiple copies of the same set in `groups`, we had a reference to the same set

```
# idx:     0    1   2        3   4       5       6       7
groups = [{0}, {1}, groupA, {3}, groupB, groupA, groupA, groupB]
```

where `groupA == {2,5,6}` and `groupB == {4,7}`

Then, to merge `groupA` and `groupB` would require at most `min(len(groupA), len(groupB))` updates:

```
if len(groupA) < len(groupB):
  groupA, groupB = groupB, groupA
# len(groupA) >= len(groupB)
groupA |= groupB
for label in groupB:
  groups[label] = groupA
```

which would result in

```
# idx:     0    1   2        3   4       5       6       7
groups = [{0}, {1}, groupA, {3}, groupA, groupA, groupA, groupA]
```

where `groupA == {2,4,5,6,7}`

---

Is there a more efficient way to merge groups? Is Union-Find (Disjoin Set Union) data structure the way?

Comment: Wait, you *know* about union-find data structures already? Just use those! They're designed for the job, and *way* more efficient than anything you can do with standard `set`s.